# GCP - GoogleCredential vs GoogleCredentials

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating GPC clients for BigQuery & Transfer API, using GCP Java API.
To each client I need to initiate different type of credentials -

[GoogleCredential javadoc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential) - for Transfer API

[GoogleCredentials javadoc](http://google.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.6.0/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html) - for BigQuery

Is there a convenient way to convert between the two so I won't need to manage reading two types of credentials?

Also - could anyone reason why there was a need for these two types?

Comment: Are you using the new libraries (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java)? I think you're using the older ones. If you use the new ones, you don't need to use those classes at all. Simply use `BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();` and `DataTransferServiceClient client = DataTransferServiceClient.create()`

Comment: @GrahamPolley thanks for your comment. I need to provide credentials as I can't use the default account (I manage multiple projects)

Comment: Ahh, I see. So, you use one project for BigQuery, and another for the Datatrasnfer service you mean? And they are both in your same code base/project? I'd probably split them into seperate projects and each one uses its own service account to be honest.

Comment: This is the case and it's already happening. The issue is with different types of credentials needed for each. Though both hold service accounts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [HttpCredentialsAdapter](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/http/HttpCredentialsAdapter.java) to use the more recent `GoogleCredentials` with the Google API Client Libraries for Java.

I don't know of a way to do the reverse transformation, i.e., generate a `GoogleCredential` from `GoogleCredentials`.

Comment: You saved my day :) `new XXXAPI.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpCredentialsAdapter(serviceAccountCredentials))` works perfetly.